# Migrating from tp_smapi to 'normal' ACPI support in 2.6.36

Tags: linux, kernel, thinkpad, acpi

I used [zen kernel patchset](http://zen-kernel.org/) for a long time which included tp_smapi patch. Recently in zen-stable tp_smapi was removed as "We no longer need tp_smapi as of 2.6.36 - the in-kernel thinkpad acpi support is better.". How to port following code to in-kernel thinkpad acpi:

```
echo 40 > /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh
echo 40 > /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/start_charge_thresh
echo 60 > /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh
echo 60 > /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT1/stop_charge_thresh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not be possible. At least there is nothing in the [documentation of thinkpad-acpi](http://repo.or.cz/w/linux-2.6/linux-acpi-2.6/ibm-acpi-2.6.git/blob_plain/release/2.6.35:/Documentation/laptops/thinkpad-acpi.txt), nothing in the [release notes](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ibm-acpi/thinkpad-acpi/0.24-20100516/thinkpad-acpi-0.24-20100516.release-notes.txt?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fibm-acpi%2Ffiles%2F&ts=1288126769&use_mirror=mesh), nothing in the [thinkpad-acpi thinkwiki page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thinkpad-acpi) and no mentioning of tp_smapi being obsolete in [the tp_smapi thinkwiki page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi).